# move up and down array values on click options using knockout js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I am new in knockoutjs, I saw an example, which moves up and down array values by selecting the dropdown values of the index in the option. But its problem is they dont't move the values correctly. And after changing the array position options in select box will be changed..

```js
var viewModel = function() {
  var self = this;

  var Item = function(name, pos) {
    this.name = ko.observable(name);
    this.position = ko.observable(pos);
    var oldPosition = pos;
    this.position.subscribe(function(newValue) {
      self.reposition(this, oldPosition, newValue);
      oldPosition = newValue;
    }, this);
  };

  this.items = [
    new Item("item Three", "3"),
    new Item("item One", "1"),
    new Item("item Two", "2"),
    new Item("item Five", "5"),
    new Item("item Four", "4"),
    new Item("item Six", "6")
  ];


  self.orderedItems = ko.computed(function() {
    return ko.utils.arrayFilter(this.items, function(item) {
      return true;
    }).sort(function(a, b) {
      return a.position() - b.position();
    });
  });

  self.curName = ko.observable();

  self.reposition = function(item, oldPosition, newPosition) {
    console.debug("Reposition", item, oldPosition, newPosition);
  };

};

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<div class='liveExample'>
  <ul data-bind="foreach: orderedItems">
    <li>
      <div> <span data-bind="text: name"> </span> has Position:
        <select id="pos" data-bind=" options: orderedItems,
          optionsText: 'position',
          optionsValue: 'position',
          value: position "></select>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

this is my sample code, i want to show array index position should be show in the dropdown. I want to select the index value in the dropdown the position of the array values should be change but not the opitions. How is it possible with knockout js.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So this one is a little more tricky than normal since you are basing your index on a property of the Item. It's not wrong, it just adds more complexity.

First you have to create the array of "indexes" since you aren't actually changing the index of the items, they are just computed off of the position property.

`this.items()` has been changed to an observableArray to propagate/bubble changes of the items to other functions. Now you could include an "Add Item" feature, add it to the the items array and everything would updated correctly.

I removed the subscribe function in the Item constructor, it was causing too many issues firing off when it didn't need to. Instead I attached an event handler to the select box that can manage the items and removed the two way binding of the value by getting the value().

Hope this helps and good luck!

```js
var viewModel = function() {
  var self = this;

  // UPDATED: Removed the subscribe function
  var Item = function(name, pos) {
    this.name = ko.observable(name);
    this.position = ko.observable(pos);
  };

  // UPDATED: Changed to observable so you can change items here and it will propogate down to the computed functions
  this.items = ko.observable([
    new Item("item Three", "3"),
    new Item("item One", "1"),
    new Item("item Two", "2"),
    new Item("item Five", "5"),
    new Item("item Four", "4"),
    new Item("item Six", "6")
  ]);
  
  // ADDED: Create array of index options based on length
  this.positions = ko.computed(function(){
    var numArray = [];
    for(i = 0; i < self.items().length; i++) {
      numArray.push(i + 1)
    }
    return numArray;
  })


  self.orderedItems = ko.computed(function() {
    return ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.items(), function(item) {
      return true;
    }).sort(function(a, b) {
      return a.position() - b.position();
    });
  });

  self.curName = ko.observable();

  /**
  * UPDATED: Get item at selected position, change it to the current 
  * items position, then update current items position to the selected position;
  */
  self.reposition = function(item, event) {
    var selectedPosition = event.target.value;
    var itemAtPosition = ko.utils.arrayFirst(self.items(), function(i){
      return i.position() === selectedPosition;
    })
    itemAtPosition.position(item.position());
    item.position(event.target.value)
  };

};

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<div class='liveExample'>
  <ul data-bind="foreach: orderedItems">
    <li>
      <div> <span data-bind="text: name"> </span> has Position:
        <select id="pos" data-bind=" options: positions(),
          value: position(), event: { change: reposition} "></select>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```